# How to emulate statistical command choice tab of this widget?-how to do what i ask?

Tags: functions, front-end, probability-or-statistics, programming, syntax

I designed this little program, but I want you to be able to choose what I want to look for by choosing it as you do with the widget tab, please help me.

widget
[Widget of internet](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=bb97e12829769adefec928f498a11396)

[image: what I need]

my program

```
L = {12, 20, 16, 18, 19};
Print [ "Lista de Datos =", L];
Print [ "Cantidad de Datos =", Length[L]];

Print [ "Suma  Datos =", Total[L]];
Print [ "Dato Minimo =", Min[L]];

Print [ "Dato Maximo =", Max[L]];
Print [ "Rango =", Max[L] - Min[L]];
Print [ "Media Aritmetica =", Mean[L]];
Print [ "Mediana =", Median[L]];
Print [ "Moda =", Commonest[L]];


Print [ "Media Harmonica =", HarmonicMean[L]];
Print [ "Media CONTRAHarmonica =", ContraharmonicMean[L]];

Print [ "Media Geometrica =", N[GeometricMean[L], 3]];
Print [ "Media Cuadratica =", N[RootMeanSquare[L], 3]];
Print["Desviacion Media =", MeanDeviation[L]];
Print["Variaza Muestral =", Variance[L]]
Print["Desviacion Estandar Muestral =", StandardDeviation[L]];
Print["Variaza Poblacional =", Total[(L - Mean[L])^2]/Length[L]];
Print["Desviacion Estandar Poblacional =",  Sqrt[Total[(L - Mean[L])^2]/Length[L]]];

Print["Desviacion Media =", MeanDeviation[L]];
Print["Cuartiles =", Quartiles[L]];
Print["Rango Intercuartilico =", InterquartileRange[L]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html), [`PopupMenu`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PopupMenu.html) and [`InputField`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputField.html) as follows:

```
functions = {Total, Min, Max, MinMax, Mean, Median, Commonest, Quartiles};
flabels = {"Suma  Datos", "Dato Minimo", "Dato Maximo", "Rango", "Media Aritmetica", 
   "Mediana", "Moda", "Cuartiles"};
fl = Thread[functions -> flabels];

Manipulate[Row[{f /. fl, f @ data}, " = "], 
 Row[{Control @ {{f, Total, "Calcula la "}, fl}, 
  Control@{{data, {}, "Lista de Datos ="}, ControlType ->(InputField[#, Expression]&)}},
  Spacer[10]]]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks, Thanks just what I needed, but I have a question, Mathematica when it calculates the variance and standard deviation divide by n-1, which for me is when it comes to a data sample, when it comes to the population I should divide by n, that formula in mathematics I don't find.
I can implement them with code , but if there is any command that calculates it better , do you know one or any other way to do it?

Comment: @BeTDa, you can use  `CentralMoment[data, 2]` or `Variance[data] (Length[data] - 1)/Length[data]`?

Comment: I have tried to implement it here in various ways but mathematica rejects it ;                                                   functions = {Total, Min, Max, MinMax, Mean, Median, Commonest,  Quartiles, CentralMoment[fl, 2], Sqrt[CentralMoment[fl, 2]]}

Comment: @BeTDa, try `functions = {Total, Min, Max, MinMax, Mean, Median, Commonest, Quartiles, CentralMoment[#, 2]&, Sqrt[CentralMoment[#, 2]]&}`

Comment: ,it worked thanks to

Comment: everything works well , but I can't write the result of the arithmetic mean , I have tried to implement it with N[...] or TraditionalForm but it doesn't work   
https://i.postimg.cc/Pq9yD25t/media-geometrica.png

Comment: @BeTDa if you do `N@Mean`, I believe it should work. Otherwise you’d need to do something like `N[Mean[#]]&`, replacing Mean with whatever function you’d want to use. For `TraditionalForm`, I presume you should just replace `N` with `TraditionalForm` in the previous two methods I mentioned.

Comment: @CA Trevillian ,works with  GeometricMean[N[#, 3]] & ,although I don't understand much what function the & at the end

Comment: @BeTDa look up anonymous functions—it’s akin to writing `Function[x,GeometricMean[N[x,3]]]` except without the need to use `Function`. Essentially you are saying that the `#` should be filled with whatever the function is applied to. When you use the other options, you are using something like `Max@input` except it’s is `...&@input`.